# How can I use at symbol (@) in url?

Tags: url, browser, uri

For example I meet this url type: `http://username:token@example.com/protected/files` .

I searched on the web for this but I don't find what I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia explains [the syntax of a URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) quite well:

`scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`

Comment: In this specific case better link to the URL wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: @bradbury9 Did you notice that the "Syntax" section actually refers back to the Wikipedia article on URI, which is what I originally linked?

Comment: Yup, but the description of the URL one fits better with the OP problem

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `username:token@example.com/protected/files` may look like and URL, but if fact it is not, because it does not include the protocol to access the data. It is an uri.

Browsers (I suppose you refer to web browsers) do work with URL's, which is a subtype of URI that includes the protocol. Please notice web browsers dont work with all existing protocols, only with some of them (http, https, ftp, file...) `username` is not a protocol.